# CSS Selectors scope

Tags: css

I was wondering if I could display divs according to the radio button selected without using Jquery, just pure css. Problem is I'm not sure if I can overcome the scope defined for it. Here's a mock up of what I've written for it.

```
    <div class="tester">
<input type="radio" name="chk" class="chkbox chkbox1" id="chk1" checked/>
<label for="chk1">Paypal</label>
<input type="radio" name="chk" class="chkbox chkbox2" id="chk2" />
<label for="chk2">Braintree</label>
<input type="radio" name="chk" class="chkbox chkbox3" id="chk3" />
<label for="chk3">Du</label>
  </div>
<div class="test">
  <div id="chkbox1" class="box">Paypal</div>
  <div id="chkbox2" class="box">Braintree</div>
  <div id="chkbox3" class="box">Du</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
<div id="chkbox1" class="box"> Paypal </div>
<div id="chkbox2" class="box"> Braintree </div>
<div id="chkbox3" class="box"> Du </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding:20px;
    margin:20px 0 0;
    max-height:150px;
    max-width:300px;
    display:none /* By Default the box is hidden */        
}

.chkbox1:checked ~ .test > #chkbox1, 
.chkbox2:checked ~ .test > #chkbox2,
.chkbox3:checked ~ .test > #chkbox3 {
    display: block
}
```

Any ideas?

JSfiddle for it [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/heZBT/3949/)

Comment: `.test` and `.checkbox` aren't siblings, so `~` won't work.

Comment: you would need to unwrap radio buttons from .tester, and it will work https://jsfiddle.net/x6swmdd4/

Comment: Is there no way this would work without unwrapping?

Comment: with only css I dont think so :(

Comment: There's no parent selector in CSS yet.

Comment: If you can put the `chkbox` elements into the `.tester` div, you can modify the CSS slightly to get the desired effect.